# 37#37: *146039 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/static/js/main.64520b4a.js"

Tags: nginx, redirect, config, nginx-config

While checking the GCP error log i got a issue (rewrite or internal redirection cycle).

I cannot figure out why this error is happening: "**146039 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/static/js/main.64520b4a.js**" in nginx.conf

Below is my Config file:

```
server {  
  listen 80 default_server;   
  listen [::]:80 default_server;  
  root /var/www/html;  
  server_tokens off;  
  
  location / {  
    if (-f $document_root/$maintenance_mode) {  
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance_page.html break;  
    }  
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;  
    proxy_set_header Host $host;  
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
    proxy_set_header X-Request-URI $request_uri;  
  }  
  
  location ~ .(static)/(js|css|media)/(.+)$ { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/$3;  
  }  
}
```

guys if you know the solution, kindly share

Answer (score 0):

You're `try_files` statement is redirecting to `/$1/$2/$3` which causes the continuous loop.

If the `/$1/$2/$3` is intended to be a **file** term (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)) - then it cannot be the final parameter.

For example, you could append `=404` to create a valid `try_files` statement:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/$3 =404;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info, I ll check